# jQuery Collapser hide or show content inside the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is related with "**jQuery – Collapser plugin**" ( http://www.aakashweb.com/jquery-plugins/collapser/ ):-

I am using the following script to hide or show content inside the DIV with CLASS name 'shrink'. It works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shrink').collapser({
        mode: 'words',
        truncate: 80,
        ellipsis: ' ... '
    });
});
</script>
```

But, In the BODY I use a javascript to print some content inside DIV with a table to hide or show content inside `<tr><td><div class="shrink"></div></td></tr>`. Now, hide or show content does not works. (*sample script is given below, Note: There is no line break. It is just for explanation only.*)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataTable = document.getElementById('Result');
var content = "<table class='tablesorter'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td><div class='shrink'>Some long content....</div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
dataTable.innerHTML = content;
</script>

<div id="Result"></div>
```

Also, I tried with a simple statement as below. It does not works.

```
var content = "<div class='shrink'>Some long content....</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shrink() {
  $('.shrink').collapser({
    mode: 'words',
    truncate: 80,
    ellipsis: ' ... '
  });
}
function display () {
  var dataTable = document.getElementById('Result');
  var content = "<table class='tablesorter'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td><div class='shrink'>Some long content....</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>";
  dataTable.innerHTML = content;
}
setTimeout(function(){ display(); shrink(); }, 1000);
</script>

<div id="Result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful with line breaks in javascript strings. note how syntax highlighting stops on the second line. you have to either escape them or concat them.

escaping..

```
var content = "<table class='tablesorter'>\
<thead>\
  <tr>\
  ....
</table>";
```

Note that if you escape thelinebreaks, there can't be any trailing spaces after the `\`.

concatting..

```
var content = "<table class='tablesorter'>"+
"<thead>"+
  "<tr>"+
  ....
"</table>";
```